# Update a field for all instances when a Many-to-many relationship is involved

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following:

```
class Customer(model):
    stores = models.ManyToManyField(Store, related_name = "customers")
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Subscription, through = "CustomerSubscription")

class CustomerSubscription(model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class Subscription(model):
    is_valid = models.BooleanField()
```

For a given store instance:

```
store = Store.objects.get(pk=1)
```

I want to get all the subscriptions for all the customers and set is_valid to False.

This is my attempt which appears to work:

```
customers = store.customers.all()
for c in customers:
    c.subscriptions.update(is_valid=False)
```

I then tried using prefect_related:

```
customers = store.customers.prefect_related("subscriptions")
for c in customers:
    c.subscriptions.update(is_valid=False)
```

But I don't believe I am doing this correctly as it resulted in more sql queries than my first attempt. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you run a query in a loop which create a lot of requests (and the more users you will have the more requests will be issued)
What you can do to make it easier is to pass through your CustomerSubscription class and not the customer one.

Something like:

```py
cs = CustomerSubscription.update(subscription__is_valid=False)
```

The way it works is:

It will take all tour CustomerSubscription lines and update the is_valid value of the subscription value.
Note the double underscore between subscription and is_valid, it allows you to follow links between your entries.